# Special Characters in PHP PDO Sqlite Query cause unrecognized token

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo, special-characters

I try to execute a query in PHP using PDO on Sqlite which may contain special characters (Ä,Ö,Ü,...). But I fail to execute the query. PHP returns the following Error:

> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> int(1) [2]=> string(35) "unrecognized token: "'MÄÖÜ123DE"" }

I tried to execute the query native and also in the way to use preparing statement and binding values.

```
$statement = "select * from list where param = ? and value = ?";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($statement);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $setparam);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $val,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
```

Native way:

```
$statement = "select * from list where param = '".$setparam."' and value = '".$val."'";
        $res = $db->query($statement);
```

Both ways return the same error. I use XAMPP 1.8.3-5. The used coding ist UTF-8.
In sqlitestudio the query works well.

EDIT Execute PDO:

```
$db = new PDO("sqlite:database/lists.db","","",array(
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
```

The used UTF-8 HTML meta execution:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: How do you set up your PDO handle? Which HTML page charset and `<form>` encoding are you actually using? The input looks like a Latin-1 subset to me.

Comment: The input is converted to utf-8 using the PHP command `utf8_encode`.

Comment: That sounds about right, albeit redundant if the input was already UTF-8. Make a [verifyable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, if possible. Test literal PHP strings instead of form input. Probe with `strlen("Ä")` if it's really 2 bytes. Sqlite itself is binary-agnostic, and only the tables charset-dependant (if they were created with the right `PRAGMA`; dump the table `.schema` as well).

Comment: I solved the problem. It was wheter a sqlite nor a PHP problem. It was a problem in my data.

Answer (score 0):

It happen that the database still set by default to use ISO-8859-15.
Try to execute this query before any other to fix encoding settings

```
SET NAMES "utf8"
```

Comment: Sorry your query is faulty. The correct statement would be: `PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8;`. But it hasn't any effect on my problem.